# How can the drop shadow not be limited by the parent element when using the bootstrap carousel

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I'm making the display of items using bootstrap's carousel, and my item blocks use the box-shadow attribute, however this property is limited by the parent element that wraps it.

[image]

Is there a way for my shadow to remain fully visible? hope to get help from everyone <3
my code:

```js
 <div class="partner container">
    <div class="partner-title">
      <h5>{{ setLang("title") }}</h5>
      <h2>{{ setLang("titleSecond") }}</h2>
    </div>
    <div
      id="carouselExampleIndicators2"
      class="carousel slide"
      data-ride="carousel"
      data-pause=false
    >
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div  class="carousel-item active">
          <div class="partner-logo" id="show-slide">
            <div
              class="logo-com"
              v-for="(item, index) in partners"
              :key="index"
                      >
              <img :src="`${assetsPath}${item.url}`" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="partner-logo" id="show-slide">
            <div
              class="logo-com"
              v-for="(partner, index) in partners"
              :key="index"
            >
              <img :src="`${assetsPath}${partner.url}`" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**My Style:**

```js
.partner-logo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.logo-com, .logo-com img {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.logo-com {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 94px rgb(0 56 139 / 13%);
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 134px;
    width: 265px;
    margin-top: 23px;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that you're currently using for this?

Comment: Have you used your browser's devtools inspect facility to see exactly what is limiting the shadow? Any answer from us will just be a guess without seeing the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

give some padding into the pareent or
give margin into items,

or just put `overflow: visible` in the parent element style

Comment: This will break my items layout, is there any other way?

Comment: put overflow: visible in the parent element style